# EditText is not showing virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created a dynamic screen with editText in it..but after click it is not showing the virtual keyboard.I have added these following codes..but still ot worked.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

and  this also dint worked

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

im.showSoftInput(edittext, 0);

my code is here...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LinearLayout findViewById = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicInputs);
                //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView textView = new TextView(Activity_UserInput.this);
                textView.setText("   " + map.get(KEY_NAME) + " :");
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
                //textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Layout.DIR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL));

                findViewById.addView(textView);

                EditText editText = new EditText(Activity_UserInput.this);
                editText.setText("");
                //editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);  

                findViewById.addView(editText);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try, I think you need to set focus on editText like..

```
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
```

I am not sure but try it and let me know it works or not.

Comment: no... it dint worked.i think it is becoz of emulator.i am trying it in device.

Comment: Oh.. You mean you are trying with emulator ??

Answer (score 0):

Remove from XML

```
Android:isFocusable="false"
```

If it is not post your XML please

Btw this

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
```

Is correct

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: hey all...thanks for your reply..it was a problem of avd settings..it worked properly in different avd.