# Android : show keyboard in edittext

Tags: android

Am stuck with a pretty simple issue in the Android App am coding. I have a list of `EditText` objects, one in each row.

When the user long presses the `EditText`, I need to show the keyboard. When the user does a long press, then I call this method :

```
private void setNameAsEditable(View rowView, boolean setToEditable) {

    EditText textView = (EditText) rowView
        .findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(setToEditable);
    textView.setFocusable(setToEditable);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

The edittext becomes editable (the underline and the cursor appears, as you can see below)

[image]

but the keyboard does not come up.

I tried various solutions from stackoverflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100881/edittext-is-not-showing-virtual-keyboard)), but in vain.

I even tried

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

I want the soft-keyboard to come up as soon as the user long-presses the `EditText`. Can someone please help?

Comment: In that link he tried his code on different avd and it works. u tried?

Comment: Also try giving `textView.requestFocus();` above `InputMethodManager`. Bcs, I have got only that line in addition to your code and it seems to be working fine

Comment: Thanks so much @Tamilan ! your answer together with that of Amit helped!

Answer (score 3):

Try it, for me it works fine.

```
 et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
      imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
      et.setText("hide key board");
      et.setFocusable(false);
     et.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            imm.showSoftInput(et, 0);
            et.setText("show key board long pressed");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Amit ! it helped together with Tamilan's answer

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked finally ( Amit's answer + Tamilan's answer) Thanks so much!

```
private void setNameAsEditable (View rowView, boolean setToEditable) {

    EditText textView = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(setToEditable);
    textView.setFocusable(setToEditable);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(), 0);

    if (setToEditable) {
         textView.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(textView, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have android:focusable="false" or android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in your xml layout.