# Android : Setvisibility to visible causes nullpointerexception on button

Tags: android

This seems to have been asked in stackoverflow a bit before with no convincing answers for most questions. anyways, i attempt again. 
I have an Android App where am displaying a list where each row has an Edittext and Button component as seen below

[image]

The Edittext is non-editable when the view appears. I do this with the code below:

```
private void setNameAsEditable (View rowView, boolean setToEditable) {

    EditText textView = (EditText) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(setToEditable);
    textView.setFocusable(setToEditable);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.button_save_name);

            if ( setToEditable ) {

                    button.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);  // nullpointerexception here
    } else {
        button.setVisibility (View.GONE);
    }
```

When I long-press, and setToEditable is true, it throws nullpointerexception in the line indicated above. it doesn't seem to find the button component. However, 'button.setVisibility (View.GONE);' is executed when setToEditable is false without any issue.

Can someone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : show keyboard in edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737686/android-show-keyboard-in-edittext)

Comment: You no need to ask a same question in different post.

Comment: can u post ur xml file which consist button and edittext

Comment: Must sure that your button is ImageButton or Button?

Comment: @Andru this is not a duplicate of that. That is about keyboard showing up. This is about button visibility set to on/off. They are two different issues.

Comment: can you please post your xml for reference.
i think you are missing id, can you please show exception log or xml which you have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowView` appears to be your `EditText` while you actually want the parent view that has the `button` inside of it. If you call `findViewById` and the id doesn't exist inside of that view, it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is initialization of view control. You should initialize `EditText & ImageButton` at the top.

```
      EditText textView;
      ImageButton button ;
      ...
      ...
      ...
      EditText textView = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);
      ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_save_name);
```

And next thing is try to write your code in try & catch block so you get exact idea what is wrong and where is bug.